# Open drain output with parasitic indicator LED

Tags: mosfet, led, open-drain

I'm designing a "minimal parts / as simple as possible" open drain NOR gate (also known as 2 N-MOSFETs and a wire), but I'd like it to have an output state LED.

I was thinking of having either a separate `ILED` pin, or put the LED in series with the output `Q`:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZt0qY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(pay no mind to the part numbers, i just took the editor defaults)

The way I see it, the first approach would give me certain flexibility (so `Q` can be pulled to a higher voltage than the LED, though then again the LED voltage might also pull `Q` too strong) but might have the downside of "backdriving" the LED from `Q` being pulled low externally, while the second allows for one less pin (and I'd rather not have an odd amount due to footprint niceness) but would mean I have to make sure my external pullup fits certain criteria?

Or does it actually still behave open collector and just add a voltage bias due to the forward drop? In that case, how would I make sure that those gates can actually drive each other / fan out reliably without messing with the LED?

And, finally: Since I'm pretty sure this is actually pretty bad practice, is there anything I could do with maybe an additional MOSFET and resistor (and whatever Zener or something to generate the LED supply locally?) to make an actually decent 4pin (`GND`, `A`, `B`, `Q / Pullup abused for parasitic LEDing`) circuit (that doesn't depend on a known `Q` pullup voltage, as long as it's between e.g. `1..2V` for the LED and maybe `10V` or so to be nice to the FETs)? for super bonus points: in a way that i can just not populate or short out certain components if i don't want an LED (to get just the wired-OR of the 2 FETs, so I don't need 2 PCBs for the cheaper no-blinky-option)

Comment: What else will be connected to the Q output? It matters a great deal.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I want it to be connected via a (hopefully not too strong, i hope to stay within 20-30mA per module, given there's LEDs with <20mA IF and i don't need them to be too bright anyway) pullup to anything between `3V0` and `5V5` to then feed into either more copies of this circuit (since each is a NOR gate and i want to build bigger blinky logic from it) and/or things like microcontrollers.

Comment: With either circuit you show, you do need a current-limiting resistor in series with the LED.

Comment: @PeterBennett well that would be my pullup, wouldn't it? or, on the one with ILED i provide a current (that's why it's not VLED), so yeah that would have a resistor too

Comment: @nonchip Answering my last question you said that the pullup resistor would be **connected to Q**. That won't accomplish current-limiting for left circuit, as PeterBennett is suggesting. You really should show us a complete schematic.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson but that's the thing, the complete schematic *is* that i want a "passive" NOR gate with open-drain and an indicator LED (that's ideally somehow "fed" from the output being pulled up). as in one that only needs its inputs, a common ground and an externally pulled-up output to function. alternatively i *could* settle for one that has 2 additional voltage input pins for VCC and the LED respectively and pulls up its own output, but i think that runs into issues with wired-AND (cumulative pullups becoming too strong)?

Answer (score 1):

The LED can’t be relied upon to do pull-up because of its forward voltage drop, which is a problem with both your proposals.

You need to add three things to your idea:

- Tie your LED to Vcc (5V, 3.3V)
- Add a current-limiting resistor in series with the LED. 330 ohms or so.
- Add a pull-up resistor from the FET drains to Vcc. About 2k or so, depending on your high-drive needs.

Then you take the Q output from the FET drain pins. The pull-up ensures you will have a valid GND to Vcc swing with which you can drive something. The LED being tied separately to Vcc ensures it gets adequate, but controlled current and enough voltage to overcome its forward drop.

Note that this won’t work on any Vcc voltages lower than the LED forward voltage, which varies between 2V for red and yellow to 3V or more for true green, blue or white. Check your LED data sheet.

Comment: I mean, all those things are already there (note how my LED is provided with a *current* source and I keep mentioning an external pullup), but also I just noticed my LED would be glowing when my output is low, which is the opposite of what I want... so either I need another inverter in there or maybe figure something out where the LED's limit resistor becomes half a voltage divider with the FET and gets pulled below the LED forward voltage to extinguish (though then i'd always be burning power, not just when it's on)